# Invalid array assignment?

Tags: c++

When I run the code below I get the error : invalid array assignment on lines 14 and 26. I am fairly new (1 week) to c++ so I am a bit confused. I searched and could not find an answer to solve my problem.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

 using namespace std;

 char usrname[5];
 char psswrd[9];

 cout << "Please enter your username:";
 cin >> usrname;

 if (usrname = "User")
  {
    cout << "Username correct!";
  }
  else 
  {
    cout << "Username incorrect!";
  }

 cout << "Please enter your password:";
 cin >> psswrd;

 if (psswrd = "password")
  {
    cout << "The password is correct! Access granted.";
  }
 else 
  {
    cout << "The password is incorrect! Access denied.";
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string` to start with. Even with the right number of equals signs, it's still wrong with character arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign arrays, and

```
usrname = "User"
```

does just that. Don't.

You meant

```
usrname == "User"
```

which is a comparison, **but won't compare your strings**. It just compares pointers.

Use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays or pointers and compare with `==`:

```
 #include <string>

 //...
 std::string usrname;
 cin << usrname;

  if (usrname == "User")
  //          ^^
  //   note == instead of =
```

Side question - what's the point of shortening "username" to "usrname"... you're saving a single character...

Comment: using == operator when comparing strings is wrong, you should use str1.compare(str2), for more information read : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin it's not wrong. Why would you say that? This isn't Java... It's **perfectly OK** to compare `std::string`s with `==` in C++.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin Have you heard about operator overloading? Probably `std::string::operator==` uses `strcmp()` under the hoods...

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin: From the same site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/

Comment: Thank you so much @Luchian Grigore! An to answer your side question: honestly I don’t know I guess that’s just how I typed it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use strcmp or similar.

```
if (!strcmp(usrname, "User"))
{
   cout << "Username correct!";
}
```

what you are doing is assigning a value not comparing values.